# Are there more elegant ways to prevent negative numbers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, negative-number

Given that I'd like to do the following calculation:

```
total = subtotal - discount
```

Because `discount` might be greater than `subtotal`, there is code like the following:

```rb
class Calculator
  def initialize(subtotal: subtotal, discount: discount)
    @subtotal = subtotal
    @discount = discount
  end

  def total
    [subtotal - discount, 0].max
  end

  private

  def subtotal
    @subtotal
  end

  def discount
    @discount
  end
end
```

When seeing the `[subtotal - discount, 0].max` part or any similar code, I often have to pause and think.

Are there more elegant ways to handle this kind of calculation?

Comment: It is pretty elegant as it is..

Comment: Probably not. Your solution seems plenty elegant to me.

Answer (score 29):

I think your solution is essentially correct, and probably the most readable besides a small refactor.  I might change it slightly like so:

```
  def total
    final_total = subtotal - discount
    [final_total, 0].max
  end
```

The ruby expression `[final_total, 0].max` is essentially the traditional solution in mathematics for the same function: `max {final_total, 0}`.  The difference is just notation and context.  Once you see this max expression once or twice you can read it as follows: "final_total, but at least zero".

Perhaps if you use this expression more than once you can add another `at_least_zero` method or something like in Shiko's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking we can extend the `Numeric` class?

```rb
class Numeric                                                                  
  def non_negative                                                             
    self > 0 ? self : 0                                                                      
  end                                                                          
end                                                                            

class Calculator
  def initialize(subtotal: subtotal, discount: discount)
    @subtotal = subtotal
    @discount = discount
  end

  def total
    (@subtotal - @discount).non_negative
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

A plain `if` statement might be easier to understand:

```
def total
  if discount > subtotal
    0
  else
    subtotal - discount
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Some performance numbers:

```
                        user     system      total        real
[i, 0.0].max        0.806408   0.001779   0.808187 (  0.810676)
0.0 if i < 0.0      0.643962   0.001077   0.645039 (  0.646368)
0.0 if i.negative?  0.625610   0.001680   0.627290 (  0.629439)
```

Code:

```
require 'benchmark'

n = 10_000_000
Benchmark.bm do |benchmark|
  benchmark.report('[value, 0.0].max'.ljust(18)) do
    n.times do |i|
      a = [-1*i, 0.0].max
    end
  end

  benchmark.report('0.0 if value < 0.0'.ljust(18)) do
    n.times do |i|
       a = 0.0 if -1*i < 0.0 
    end
  end

  benchmark.report('0.0 if value.negative?'.ljust(18)) do
    n.times do |i|
      a = 0.0 if (-1*i).negative?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify more, we need to add classes to be extended in **core_ext.rb** . file :
1) Create *core_ext.rb* file under **config\initializers** folder in your project.
2) Paste below as mentioned by @songyy in his answer:

```
class Numeric                                                                  
  def non_negative                                                             
    self > 0 ? self : 0                                                                      
  end                                                                          
end
```

**Reference:**
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#extending-core-classes